# Alternative to Mapbox.fireEvent

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to trigger a click event on a specific Maptobx Marker, when the corresponding button (outside of the map) gets clicked...

I tried this:

```
map.fire('click', {latLng: {lon: xxx, lat: xxx}})
```

But it seems like this api method is deprecated (according to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209411/how-to-emulate-a-click-on-a-mapbox-gl-js-map)

Is there any other alternative way to achieve this, relying only on Mapbox API?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
map.fire('click',{lngLat: {lon: lon, lat: lat }});
```

ended up this is working. closing questions

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`map.fire('click', { latLng: coords, point: map.project(coords), originalEvent: {} })`

From: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5060